# Can I put a whole list value once instead of "RightPush" a item many times in redis?

Tags: java, nosql, redis, spring-data-redis

I want to put a whole list to redis, but I find that there is only ***RightPush*** method can be used. for which I need to loop through all items in my list and ***RightPush*** each item for many times. I think it is not smart way to go and it cost performance.

**Can I put a whole list value once instead of RightPush a item many times in redis?**

Answer (score 1):

The Redis [`RPUSH` command](http://redis.io/commands/rpush) supports multiple arguments - so you can issue a:

```
RPUSH myList 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

command (for example), rather than issuing 10 commands:

```
RPUSH myList 1
RPUSH myList 2
# ... etc. ...
```

Looking at the docs it looks like this *might* be possible with an instance of `org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisList` (ah, Java) - it has a `addAll` method that takes a `Collection`.

However, if `DefaultRedisList` is implemented using `redis.core.ListOperations` then you may need to roll your own implementation of `RPUSH key value1 [...valueN]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, in `DefaultRedisList` v1.0.2 implementation class, it directly use `ListOperations.RightPush` in a for loop.

Comment: What kind of run times are you seeing pushing the whole list through @Sean Viera's method? My guess is the vast majority of the time consumed would be spent sending the list over your network rather than inserting items one by one into memory. I strongly suspect inserting the whole thing at once wouldn't make any difference.